# Use of delegatecall with msg.data

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I'm trying to understand below code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Relay {
    address public currentVersion;
    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function Relay(address initAddr) {
        currentVersion = initAddr;
        owner = msg.sender; // this owner may be another contract with multisig, not a single contract owner
    }

    function changeContract(address newVersion) public onlyOwner(){
        currentVersion = newVersion;
    }

    function() {
        require(currentVersion.delegatecall(msg.data));
    }
}
```

This code is for maintaining version of a contract, but I'm not getting use of fallback function here.
 I know that `msg.data` is complete calldata which is non-modifiable, but have no idea use of `delegatecall` here.

Answer (score 4):

The fallback function gets called when no other function matches the calldata signature. In this code, the fallback functions is used as a universal function.

This is done by forwarding the calldata to the contract at `currentVersion`. Forwarding the calldata to another smart contract results in it running the proper funcion. There are two ways to do this: `address.call` and `address.delegatecall`. The difference between those is the context in which the receiving contract is going to run the code.

With `delegatecall`, the receiving contract accesses the `Relay` contract's storage. This way, the receiving contract can alter all fields of the `Relay`.

Effectively, by updating `currentVersion`, `Relay` can update it's code without changing it's address or migrating it's storage contents.

Docs:

- [Fallback functions](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html?highlight=fallback%20function#fallback-function)
- [`call` and `delegatecall`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#members-of-addresses)

Comment: Thanks! could you please explain what do you mean by *Forwarding the calldata to another smart contract results in it running the proper funcion*

Comment: As `currentVersion` is not a contract right? it's a state variable

Comment: That's correct, but it's an address that should be pointing to a smart contract, as external accounts can't be called

Comment: Okay, I understand it partially, I think in order to understand this code I would need to understand fallback function and delegateCall first. I'm having doubt regarding fallback.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple of links to the documentation. Be sure to check them out

Comment: Thanks for the links! what I have understood is If I'm calling any function of my smart contract and howsoever, argument doesn't match then even fallback function will call, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, correct. The signature of a function is defined by it's name and the arguments (ordered) that it takes

Comment: And how can I check fallback function is getting called every time on Remix, I have been checked, but it only get executed by user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81399/discussion-between-henk-and-div).